# Path.GetDirectoryName() isn't returning ArgumentException for empty path in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am migrating my code from .Net Framework to .Net Core and there I am seeing one regression in API called `Path.GetDirectoryName()`. Though I am passing an empty value (i.e. "") to it, it's not returning me `System.ArgumentException` but instead returning me `null` value.

This used to work fine in .Net Framework and that's how the behavior should be in .Net Core according to documentation:

> // Exceptions:
>
> // T:System.ArgumentException:
>
> // The path parameter contains invalid characters, is empty, or
>   contains only white // spaces.

Comment: I've voted to close this question, on the basis that it seems to describe a bug that should be reported. There is no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/4a514a62115ccf94636ca96e2d32af7d330d05f6/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Path.cs#L76) documentation for `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the directory portion of a file path. This method effectively
/// removes the last segment of the given file path, i.e. it returns a
/// string consisting of all characters up to but not including the last
/// backslash ("\") in the file path. The returned value is null if the
/// specified path is null, empty, or a root (such as "\", "C:", or
/// "\\server\share").
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Directory separators are normalized in the returned string.
/// </remarks>
public static string GetDirectoryName(string path)
{
    if (path == null || PathInternal.IsEffectivelyEmpty(path.AsSpan()))
        return null;

    int end = GetDirectoryNameOffset(path.AsSpan());
    return end >= 0 ? PathInternal.NormalizeDirectorySeparators(path.Substring(0, end)) : null;
}
```

so, it is not the same as in full framework version and returns `null` if the
specified path is null, empty, or a root. It is expected behavior

Comment: Ahh I see but then documentation should also be changed, when I did GetDefinition from Visual Studio, I found the same documentation as that of .Net Framework.